# About delegate and XMLParser iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, bonjour, nsnetservice

I am absolutely new to MAC and iPhone. I am going to develop an application that performs a connection to a webservice server that contains some movie files to open it. Does anyone give me some instruction to study or guide me how to develop it. Now I just find that I can use NSNetService or CFNetService class. Thank you so much.

Comment: delegates used to access methods in one class to another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delegates are created by @protocal, use this link
[basic for delegates example](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/simple-objective-c-protocol-example/)

xml parser simple example [XMLparser example](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/09/parsing-xml-in-an-iphone-app-tutorial/)

Comment: I have finished parsing XML file to get path of videos that contains  the file information such as local path on the server, the server has its own domain name, service name, port information. The information of video only contains in a XML file, how can I access the movie and open it on my iphone

Answer (score 0):

Delegate - Delegate is passing the message from one object to another object when event happens.
for implementing protocols using delegate methods.

Xml Parser: For parsing the sever response using xml parser
there are three main methods in xml parser
1) didstartelement
2) found characters
3) didendelement